# NetBeans location of server.xml using Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, netbeans

I am using NetBeans 7.0.1 making a web app running in Tomcat 7. When building and running, what server.xml file located where is used when running Tomcat from within NetBeans ?

Comment: you want to get to know what server.xml file is used, am I right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. At the moment it doesn't seem to use the standard one in my tomcat folder, so I am assuming there is a per project server.xml that NetBeans creates, but I can't locate it.

Answer (score 2):

You can add  the desired server to the netbeans. Simply click on Tools menu -> Servers and click Add server button. Then choose the folder where your server is located(root folder of server). So it will use the configuration of that server.
Another opportunity to configure the servers in netbeans: On the servers dialog choose Startup tab and specify the catalina script there